# Mobile Backend Starter deployment on Google Cloud seems to be stuck

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to deploy mobile backend starter on Google Cloud console but it seems to be stuck at the following step :

```
Uploading 0 files.
Cloning 87 application files.
Deploying new version.
Will check again in 1 seconds.
Uploading cron jobs.
Closing update: new version is ready to start serving.
Uploading task queues.
Uploading index definitions.
Updated successfully
Install running
```

Comment: I am getting this too. Did you find a way around this other than starting fresh?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably deployed. Just go to http://your-project-id.appspot.com. It'll ask for your permission to login from your Google account, just do that and the admin configuration page will come up. Check open and save. Then you can follow the next steps in the [Getting Started Doc](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/deploy_backend).